# How to find the Parent of a CustomControl from inside the CustomControl

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-tree

I have a class which extends `Canvas` in WPF.

This class is placed in a `ScrollViewer`.

Without passing a specific reference to the `ScrollViewer` into the `Canvas`, I want to find the `ScrollViewer` which contains the `Canvas` from within the `Canvas` itself.

The `Parent` property of the class which extends `Canvas` is `null`, and every attempt to use the `VisualTreeHelper` just returns `null` as well.

I have attempted to find the visual ancestor using `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this)`, however the parent property is null.

As the `ExtendedCanvas` will be used in multiple instances, I would like it to be able to resolve its containing `ScrollViewer` without the need to  specifically reference the `ScrollViewer` in either code behind or in XAML.

I realise that I could add a dependency propery in the `ExtendedCanvas` and create a binding in the `XAML`, however I would like the component to work by simply dropping it into a container.

Similarly, I would not be averse to placing the `ScrollViewer` onto a panel of some sort, then placing my `ExtendedCanvas` within it, so that my component uses that panel as its lowermost containing element.

What is puzzling me is that as I understand it, the `VisualTreeHelper` will navigate the entire visual tree for the running application. It seems that either my assumption is entirely wrong, or it can only navigate downwards from the specified component.

Is this possible to achieve without the above approaches?

Example Code:

cs -

```
public class ExtendedCanvas:Canvas {

    //I wish to automatically populate this scroll viewer
    //reference to the instance of the scrollviwer which contains
    //this ExtendedCanvas instance
    private ScrollViewer _containingScrollViewer = null;

}
```

xaml -

```
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
        <local:ExtendedCanvas x:Name="extendedCanvas" />
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find its parent like this:

```
    public ExtendedCanvas()
    {
        //it hasn't been added to its parent yet
        Loaded += ExtendedCanvas_Loaded;
    }

    private void ExtendedCanvas_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //now it is added to its parent
        _containingScrollViewer  = Parent as ScrollViewer;
    }
```

Comment: I'm still a little lost as to why the parent property is null when I've examined it from within the constructor though. My best guess is that the parent is simply not set until after the constructor has returned. Am I right in that assumption?

Comment: yes. in the constructor it hasn't been added to its parent yet